# Microsoft SQL Server does not store full value of Base64 encoded string

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I am trying to store a Base64 encoded full size image taken from camera(android) in string format in MSSQL server. Referred [Save the full-size photo](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)

The encoded string generated from code gives proper string but when  I save the  same string in MSSQL server, it is half of encoded string. Tried VARCHAR(MAX) and NVARCHAR(MAX) to store the string but same issue.
Here are my codes.

```
//Method to encode bitmap
     public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
            Bitmap immagex=image;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
            return imageEncoded;
        }


  @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                SendImageString="";

                if (mCurrentPhotoPath!=null){
                    File image = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                    try {
                         Bitmap myBitmap = new 
                         Compressor(this).compressToBitmap(image);
                        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 
                        800, 600, true);
                        img_takenpisture.setImageBitmap(resized);
                        SendImageString = encodeTobase64(resized);
                        IsImageClick=true;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want to save this as (n)varchar?
You could also save it binary using varbinary(max).